# Python Sendgrid send email with PDF attachment file

Tags: python, pdf, email-attachments, sendgrid

I'm trying to attach a PDF file to my email sent with sendgrid.

Here is my code :

```
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))

from_email = Email("from@example.com")
subject = "subject"
to_email = Email("to@example.com")
content = Content("text/html", email_body)

pdf = open(pdf_path, "rb").read().encode("base64")
attachment = Attachment()
attachment.set_content(pdf)
attachment.set_type("application/pdf")
attachment.set_filename("test.pdf")
attachment.set_disposition("attachment")
attachment.set_content_id(number)

mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
mail.add_attachment(attachment)

response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())

print(response.status_code)
print(response.body)
print(response.headers)
```

But the Sendgrid Python library is throwing an error HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Could you check if the request is vlid using https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/v3_Mail_Send/sandbox_mode.html

Comment: I think the problem is around the base64 line. If i set the content like here https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/ca96c8dcd66224e13b38ab8fd2d2b429dd07dd02/examples/helpers/mail/mail_example.py#L66 it works. But when I'm using my pdf file with base64 encoded I got the error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found a solution. I replaced this line :

```
pdf = open(pdf_path, "rb").read().encode("base64")
```

By this :

```
with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
```

Now it works. I can send encoded file in the set_content :

```
attachment.set_content(encoded)
```

**Note:** The answer above works for Sendgrid v2 or lower. For v3 and up use:

```
encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
```

Comment: Just as a side note. You do not need to `f.close()` since the file is closed when exiting the `with` statement.

Answer (score 12):

This is my solution, Works with Sendgrid V3

```
    # Where it was uploaded Path.
    file_path = "MY_FILE_PATH"

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()

    # Encode contents of file as Base 64
    encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()

    """Build attachment"""
    attachment = Attachment()
    attachment.content = encoded
    attachment.type = "application/pdf"
    attachment.filename = "my_pdf_attachment.pdf"
    attachment.disposition = "attachment"
    attachment.content_id = "PDF Document file"

    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

    from_email = Email("origin@gmail.com")
    to_email = Email('recipient@gmail.com')
    content = Content("text/html", html_content)

    mail = Mail(from_email, 'Attachment mail PDF', to_email, content)
    mail.add_attachment(attachment)

    try:
        response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
    except urllib.HTTPError as e:
        print(e.read())
        exit()
```

Answer (score 11):

Straight from the [Sendgrid docs](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/use_cases/attachment.md):

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import base64
import os
import json
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import (Mail, Attachment, FileContent, FileName, FileType, Disposition, ContentId)

import os
import json
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

message = Mail(
    from_email='from_email@example.com',
    to_emails='to@example.com',
    subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
    html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')
file_path = 'example.pdf'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
attachment = Attachment()
attachment.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
attachment.file_type = FileType('application/pdf')
attachment.file_name = FileName('test_filename.pdf')
attachment.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
attachment.content_id = ContentId('Example Content ID')
message.attachment = attachment
try:
    sendgrid_client = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
    response = sendgrid_client.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```

Comment: Yes it's in the doc now because they took my code. I got rewarded for this. They sent me sendgrid goodies for contribution ^^

Comment: How does one attach more than one file to a message? `Property 'attachments' cannot be set`.

Comment: hi, i am going to try this method to send an email with attachment, 
what can i fill ContentID with?

Answer (score 1):

> "How does one attach more than one file to a message?"

Build additional attachments:

```py
file_path = 'test_filename1.pdf'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
attachment1 = Attachment()
attachment1.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
attachment1.file_type = FileType('application/pdf')
attachment1.file_name = FileName('test_filename1.pdf')
attachment1.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
attachment1.content_id = ContentId('Example Content ID1')

file_path = 'test_filename2.pdf'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.close()
encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()
attachment2 = Attachment()
attachment2.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
attachment2.file_type = FileType('application/pdf')
attachment2.file_name = FileName('test_filename2.pdf')
attachment2.disposition = Disposition('attachment')
attachment2.content_id = ContentId('Example Content ID2')

mail.attachment = [attachment1,attachment2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works for me:

```
    mail = Mail(
        from_email=SendgridEmail(from_email_str),
        to_emails=[To(e) for e in to_emails],
        subject=email_subject,
        html_content=HtmlContent(email_html_content)
    )
    attachment = Attachment(
        file_content=file_content_b64_encoded,
        file_name=filename,
        file_type=file_type,
        disposition='attachment',
        content_id=filename
    )
    mail.add_attachment(attachment)
```