# Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable when trying to send a file from S3 as an email attachment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sendgrid-api-v3

Error message:

> "errorMessage": "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable"

```
def _get_file():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Object(S3_BUCKET_NAME, S3_ITEM_NAME)
    return obj.get()['Body'].read()

def _send_email_with_ebook(email):
    data = {
        ...
        "attachments": [
            {
                "content": _get_ebook_file(),
                "type": "application/pdf",
                "filename": "my_file.pdf"
            }
        ]
    }

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(SENDGRID_API_KEY), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(SENDGRID_API_URL, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python requests file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload)

Comment: Check please https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not sure how to use it when I need to send JSON in the following structure: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html#-Request-Body-Parameters

Comment: You can try use sendgrid sdk - https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python#quick-start

Comment: And check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656019/python-sendgrid-send-email-with-pdf-attachment-file

Comment: I answered hope it's help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need encode to base64 your file content for example:

```
import base64

def _get_file():
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Object(S3_BUCKET_NAME, S3_ITEM_NAME)
    return obj.get()['Body'].read()

def _send_email_with_ebook(email):
    data = {
        ...
        "attachments": [
            {
                "content": base64.b64encode(_get_ebook_file()),
                "type": "application/pdf",
                "filename": "my_file.pdf"
            }
        ]
    }

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(SENDGRID_API_KEY), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(SENDGRID_API_URL, json=data, headers=headers)
```