# Sendgrid Attachment : Object type of bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, sendgrid

I am trying to send a python `dict` as a JSON file for an email attachment using the `sendgrid` package.

Here is the code :

```
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid import Mail
from sendgrid import Email
from sendgrid import Attachment

final_data = {"user":{"email": "test@gmail.com", "username": "test1"}}
result = json.dumps(final_data)
print(f"Result type {type(result)}")
encoded = base64.b64encode(result.encode("utf-8"))
print(f"encoded : {encoded}")
attachment = Attachment(file_content=encoded, file_name="user.json", file_type="application/json")
message.add_attachment(attachment)
sg.send(message)
```

And the line `sg.send(message)` is throwing the error : `Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

I have seen so many SO questions about how to encode to `base64`, but i actually did and here is the whole trace of this code snippet :

```
Result type <class 'str'>
encoded : b'eyJ1c2VyIjogeyJsYXN0TmFtZSI6ICJCb2JvIiwgImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6ICJCb2JvIiwgImVtYWlsIjogImJvcmlzLmZhcmVsbEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCAidGVsIjogIiIsICJiaXJ0aGRhdGUiOiAwLCAicGhvdG9VcmwiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yYWdlLmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2luZmVlbGliL2RvY3VtZW50cy91c2Vycy9qVHBBdGRBS1lCV2V2YWUwajJLVHBSalByeUMzL3Byb2ZpbGUvMGE0ZTQzYjEtMWQzZS00ODk0LWJjYWItNGFkYTFhZDY3ODFkLmpwZz9YLUdvb2ctQWxnb3JpdGhtPUdPT0c0LVJTQS1TSEEyNTYmWC1Hb29nLUNyZWRlbnRpYWw9ZmlyZWJhc2UtYWRtaW5zZGstbmU0emElNDBpbmZ0ZWFtLWkuaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20lMkYyMDIzMDcwOSUyRmF1dG8lMkZzdG9yYWdlJTJGZ29vZzRfcmVxdWVzdCZYLUdvb2ctRGF0ZT0yMDIzMDcwOVQxMDQ2MDlaJlgtR29vZy1FeHBpcmVzPTYwNDgwMCZYLUdvb2ctU2lnbmVkSGVhZGVycz1ob3N0JlgtR29vZy1TaWduYXR1cmU9Mjk2MjY4MjY1MTA3NGMyN2VkMmY5MmY1YzBkYWM4N2JhYTIzODY0N2Q4NzFhYTk3ZTIyZmE3ZjE5MjcyNWEwN2ZiN2U4NzAxZGU4ZmJlYmIyOGZiMWVmZjdlMWY5MGQ3NzZmNTU3OTRiMTVlOTEwMzkyMTM0MmNlNzE4YzQ5ZWZjOTdlNjk1Njk3YTg0Nzk5OTQyODY4NDliMjcyYmZmMzdjM2I0MzE5ZWM1NmZlNDk2N2YzZDczM2Q5ZTMzZWMxZjJjOWFiZTUyYjA2OWJhZmU0MTA5OTMxMWFhYmQ4MTU2MzgyNDVmZWYzYjdhNzY5M2I2OGE3Njc3NzFhMjZkYWIzY2E1NGRkZDdkYTJlYTJlYTcyZjZlOGE5YmYzYjJiNTZjOWNiOTdmZTZhOTZiZjczYjI5ZTNiN2E5YTlmODI1ZDA3MTkxNWIwYTQ1ZWYwZjE1MmJmOTEyYzQxNmVlYThmOWEzZGIyNDg3ZTc4YzIxYTM3MGZiZmYxMzg4NDZhMTI3ZDk5NDk4NTQzZGIyYzA1ZjFmNGNmMjc4YTQ3MTg2MTM0ODczZTAxNzY5ZmU4YzliNjIxMmRmMTdiZjI1NDQ2Y2RkM2M2NjgyZjNmZWIyMThiMTZkNTNmZWU0YTU3ODhjOTAxMWRlNTA5NjExZjY5MjI1Yzk5NmUwNWRhNmUifX0='
ERROR:root:export_all_data: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

EDIT :

I have changed my code to use :

```
from sendgrid import FileContent
from sendgrid import FileName
from sendgrid import FileType
attachment = Attachment(file_content=FileContent(encoded), file_name=FileName("user.json"),
                                file_type=FileType("application/json"))
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send) but it's still failing, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please mention what modules you have imported? So that we can know what is the return type of the add_attachment method!

Comment: Yes sure i have updated the question ! the `add_attachment` method returns nothing and the error occurs on the `send` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ERROR:root:export_all_data: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
> ```

Looking at [`sendgrid-python` / use cases / attachment](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/main/use_cases/attachment.md), I see there is that the SendGrid API requires the base64-encoded attachment to be in a string format, not in bytes.
After calling `base64.b64encode(result.encode("utf-8"))`, it will return a *bytes* object, which is not JSON serializable. Therefore, you need to *decode* the bytes to string before passing it to the `FileContent()`.

And I do not see "`decode()`" anywhere in your question.

You can see that change in this updated code:
(but also illustrated in "[Python Sendgrid send email with PDF attachment file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58347465/6309)")

```py
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid import Mail
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Email, To, Content, Attachment, FileContent, FileName, FileType

import json
import base64

final_data = {"user":{"email": "test@gmail.com", "username": "test1"}}
result = json.dumps(final_data)
print(f"Result type {type(result)}")

# base64 encode the json string and decode the bytes to string
encoded = base64.b64encode(result.encode("utf-8")).decode()

print(f"encoded : {encoded}")

# Initialize a Mail object
email = Mail(
    from_email=Email('your-email@example.com'),
    to_emails=To('test@gmail.com'),
    subject='Subject',
    plain_text_content='Content',
)

# Attach the file
attachment = Attachment()
attachment.file_content = FileContent(encoded)
attachment.file_name = FileName("user.json")
attachment.file_type = FileType("application/json")
email.add_attachment(attachment)

# Use your SendGrid API key
sg = SendGridAPIClient('your_sendgrid_api_key')

# Send the email
response = sg.send(email)
```

Do replace `'your-email@example.com'` and `'your_sendgrid_api_key'` with your actual email and SendGrid API key.

Comment: Thanks it's working fine with the `decode` ! I saw the documentation that was asking for bytes in `Attachment` for the `file_content` param, because at first i was not using `FileContent`